# How to use some property of parent class in child class Vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, properties, parent-child, parent

Lets say I have a class named as "Class Section" having two properties i.e. area and mElement. Like this:

```
    Public Class ClassSection

    Public Property area as double 
    Public Property mElement as ClassElement

    End Class
```

Now i want to use ClassSection (parent class) property "area" in mElement. Like this in below code.

```
    Public Class ClassElement

    Public Sub CalculateAreaRatio()
    Dim AreaRatio as Double
    AreaRatio=Area/10 'This area is ClassSection Area
    End Sub
    
    End Class
```

How this can be done. Thank you in advance

Comment: There is no child-parent relationship between ClassSection and ClassElement. ClassSection _contains_ ClassElement, but this last one doesn't know anything about its container, unless you pass the container in the constructor of ClassElement or set a property of ClassElement with a reference to its container.

Comment: @Steve, Thanks i got your point. But can you please show me through one code example.

Comment: Ok It Solved. I do it Like this

    `Public Class ClassElement

     Public Property mSection As ClassSecion
         Public Sub New(mySec As ClassSecion)
         mSection = mySec
         End Sub
End Class`

Comment: Yes you can have a public property in the ClassElement or not (as in my answer below). The important thing is to have the instance of the ClassSection container available when you run the calculation

Comment: The alternative to the `ClassElement` knowing about the `ClassSection` that contains it is for the element to raise an event that the section handles and then the section does the work. This is much like a `Button` raising a `Click` event and then the form handling that and performing an action in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have said in my comment every ClassElement that you create is unaware if it is contained in a ClassSection element or not. If you want to let know each element of this relationship you should pass the container to the ClassElement instance.

So let's change the ClassElement structure to this one

```
Public Class ClassElement

    Dim myParent As ClassSection
    
    Public Sub New(parent As ClassSection )
        myParent = parent
    End Sub
    
    Public Function CalculateAreaRatio() As Double
        Dim AreaRatio As Double
        AreaRatio = MyParent.Area / 10 'This area is ClassSection Area
        Return AreaRatio
    End Function 
End Class
```

Now every time you create a ClassElement you are forced to pass into the constructor code the ClassSection container. And you save the instance passed in a private field. This private field can be used inside the CalculateAreaRatio.

The calling code could be something like this one

```
Dim section As ClassSection = New ClassSection With {
        .area = 3
}
section.mElement = New ClassElement(section)
Console.WriteLine(section.mElement.CalculateAreaRatio())
```